# Implementing biometric authentication in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, security, mobile

I'm currently developing a flutter mobile application which uses Firebase for authentication. I'm thinking of using the [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package for user login which should help in avoiding re-entering of username and password for subsequent login after registration and enabling biometrics.

Now if I use [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth), then how can I approach in linking that particular user with this biometric?